# How can I export to a spreadsheet with Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using Google Big Query's new UI. So how can I export the results of sql on a spreadsheet? I can export it by switching the screen to the old UI, but it seems that it can not be export with the new UI.The result will be returned as follows.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=undefined
=>404

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you are exporting aggregated/limited data instead of exporting huge raw data. It's working & pretty straightforward in the new UI.

You can go to save results & select google sheets to export aggregated data. 
[image]

Save notification
[image]

Once you click open, it will take you to the respective sheet
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Saving query results to Google Sheets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#saving_query_results_to_google_sheets)

To save query results to Google Sheets:

1- Go to the BigQuery web UI.

2- Click the Compose Query button.

3- Enter a valid BigQuery SQL query in the New Query text area.

4- Click Show Options.

5- (Optional) For Processing Location, click Unspecified and choose your data's location.

6- Click Run Query.

7- When the results are returned, click the Save to Google Sheets button above the query results.

8- If necessary, follow the prompts to log into your Google account and click Allow to give BigQuery permission to write the data to your Google Drive MY Drive folder. After following the prompts, you should receive an email with the subject "BigQuery Client Tools connected to your Google Account". The email contains information on the permissions you granted along with steps to remove the permissions.

9- When the results are saved, a message like the following appears above the query results in the BigQuery web UI: Results saved to Google Sheets. Click to view. Click the link in the message to view your results in Google Sheets, or navigate to your MY Drive folder and open the file manually. When you save query results to Google Sheets, the file name begins with results-[DATE] where [DATE] is today's date in the format YYYYMMDD.